# Swagger Auto-generated Python Flask Server `ImportError: No module named 'swagger_server.models...'`

Tags: python-3.x, flask, swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

Using the [online editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/) and a swagger YAML file, I generated a python flask rest server application.

According to the README.md included in the generated server zip file, I executed

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 -m my_server
```

Instead of running the server, however, the second line gave me an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/projects/my_server/python-flask-server/swagger_server/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .encoder import JSONEncoder
  File "/home/projects/my_server/python-flask-server/swagger_server/encoder.py", line 3, in <module>
from swagger_server.models.base_model_ import Model
  File "/home/projects/my_server/python-flask-server/swagger_server/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .inline_response_200 import InlineResponse200
  File "/home/projects/my_server/python-flask-server/swagger_server/models/inline_response_200.py", line 4, in <module>
from swagger_server.models.inline_response200_data import InlineResponse200Data
ImportError: No module named 'swagger_server.models.inline_response200_data'
```

I followed the instructions precisely (all two steps...) and did not write or change any python code myself. Also my YAML file is correct according to the online editor (otherwise I wouldn't have been able to generate the server anyway, I guess).

What is going wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new if you've not done so.

Comment: this is probably tracked at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4684